# How to refer an object of himself with out saying his name in C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform, gameobject

I have several objects which I need to calculate distance form the main point(main) and increase distence betwen main and each object surrounding it, by  taken chaos value.
But I don't want to put a different script to each one. I want same script in each one.

To put it simply , this is what I am trying :
222  =                   2  2  2

212=   2  1 2

222= 2 2 2

// 1 is main point

// 2 is other objects surrounding it

So how can I refer to object himself without saying his name ?

OR should I change the way I am intended to do?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DistanceMovement : MonoBehaviour
{

public int chaos = 0;
public GameObject main;        // I referred the main object
                               // which we calculete distance from
 float distance;                 

void Start()
{
    float distance = chaos;      // firts checking
}

void Update()
{
    // Gets the distance between 2 objects 
float distances = Vector3.Distance (main.transform.position, object2.transform.position);
    //how can I do that without saying objects name but saying it his himself??
    

    // checks whether there was increase in chaos lvls
     if (chaos - distance >= 0)
    {
        chaos - distance += distances;
    } 
}
         
}
```

Comment: Your main goal is not clear for me. What is main object? what is object2? This code will be attached to which gameobject? What is "Refer the script himself"?

Comment: I improved edit I hope it is more understandable  :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess what you mean is simply

```
float distances = Vector3.Distance (main.transform.position, transform.position);
```

where [`transform`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component-transform.html) is a property of `MonoBehaviour` (which your class inherits from) and returns

> The `Transform` attached to this `GameObject`.

so the `Transform` of the `GameObject` this component is attached to.

Comment: so simply I actually don't need to write anything ?

Comment: yes ^^ This basically equals writing `this.transform` or also `this.gameObject.transform` .. but usually in `c#` you can skip the `this` if there are no name conflicts with parameters

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `object2.transform.position` , use `transform.position` , It will work and it refers to the gameObject to which your script is attacked.
Also for simplification , you can first declare `Vector3 name = transform.position` and then use that vector if you need to use it repeatedly.